# OS X Mail is showing this warning.. Mail[378]: No worthy mechs found ... what is it

Tags: macos, email, postfix-mta, sasl, osx-yosemite

Note that the warning message in Syslog, isn't proceeded by any SASL warnings. Unless "Mail[378]" is exactly that.

```
Mail[378]: No worthy mechs found
```

I can't find any solution to this, and basically have no idea what it's referring to? So if anyone knows, I'd love to hear about it.
postfi-3.1+dovecot+sasl+tls+mysql on OSX 10.10.3

Comment: Try asking on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this problem (on a system that was NOT running postfix) by changing the authentication method on one email account from Password to MD5 Challenge-Response.